# Passing selected value in SELECT tag using serializeArray

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How do i pass the selected value in a `SELECT` tag with serializeArray?I tried the followng code but when i click post it empties the select tag option.

***html***

```
<form action="" name="frm" id="frm" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" name="title_val" value="abc" id="title_val"/>
                    <select name="test" id="test">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
            <a href="javascript:;" title="" id="save">post</a> 
            </form>
```

***JS***

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#save').click(function() {
            var form = $('#frm');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'topic.php',
                type:'post',
                data: form.serializeArray(),
                success: function(response) {  
                   $('#test').html(response);
                }
            }); 
        }); 

    });
```

***php***

```
<?php 
    echo $_POST['test'];  
?>
```

Comment: Try `form.serialize()` ?

Comment: what jquery version are you using ?

Comment: 1.10.2.. i think i found the problem why it was not working even the selialize.. :)

Comment: I think so, because i tested, and everything seem to be ok

Answer (score 0):

following code works for me,

```
data: form.serialize();
```